# how to route traffic of google.com from ipv6

Tags: networking, routing, ipv6

im running a openvpn server on rocky linux 9 server. it has both ipv4 and ipv6 public ip, however im trying to add a static route so i connect to google.com using ipv4.

something like this would work : `ip route add 216.58.212.174 via my_gateway dev eth0`
but nothing changes since AAAA record of google still resolves and i may connect to google using ipv6 and bypasses static route.

maybe i can force resolver to only resolve A record for this domain IDK